# Using Group By and ListAgg to get aggregate information

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, I am having an issue getting an aggregate value from the table I am working with. I am providing the sample below. But from aggregated perspective, I am not even sure where to start. I think I need to use some combination of both case and having, but I am not sure how to phrase it.

My table looks like this:

```
    Record#  Value
    111111   KA
    111111   RA
    111111   HA
    111112   KA
    111113   RA
    111114   HA
    111114   RA
```

Desired result. What I would like to get is get a count of records where:

```
    # Records only have KA only.
    # Records only have RA only.
    # Records only have RH only.
    # Records only have HA only.  
    # Records only have KA and RA.
    # Records only have KA and RH.
    # Records only have KA, RA and RH.
    and etc.
```

I have a limited number of those "Values", but I have over 1,000,000 records there, I need to understand the composition of those records.

I would create a fiddle for it, but it seems to be currently broken.

```
 create table myTable(record  varchar2(100), value varchar2(100));
 insert into myTable(record ,value) values(111111,'KA');
 insert into myTable(record ,value) values(111111,'RA');
 insert into myTable(record ,value) values(111111,'HA');
 insert into myTable(record ,value) values(111112,'KA');
 insert into myTable(record ,value) values(111113,'RA');
 insert into myTable(record ,value) values(111114,'HA');
 insert into myTable(record ,value) values(111114,'RA');
```

Edit* After using what @Gordon-Linoff suggested,

```
 select valuelist, count(*) as cnt
 from (select record, listagg(value, ',') within group (order by value) as valuelist, count(*) as cnt
       from mytable
       group by record
      ) r
 group by valuelist
 order by cnt, valuelist;
```

I got a mixed result that looked more like this

```
 KA 2
 RA 3
 HA 2
```

Instead of

```
 KA, RA, HA 2
 KA 1
 RA 1
 HA, RA 1
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: I am sorry, I just had an issue submitting the post and was convinced it was the tag issue. I apologize for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by combining the fields using `listagg()` and then aggregating by the result:

```
select valuelist, count(*) as cnt
from (select record, listagg(value, ',') within group (order by value) as valuelist, count(*) as cnt
      from mytable
      group by record
     ) r
group by valuelist
order by cnt, valuelist;
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you! I will try it in a minute and will update with results.

Comment: When using listagg, I get 

record number 

         111111  KA, KA
         111111 RA
         111111 HA

Instead of 

         111111 KA, KA, RA, HA

or even better 

         111111 KA, RA, HA

Comment: Found my own issue, I had an extra group by :)